# TypeScript and Chrome Notification

Tags: push-notification, typescript, tslint

I'm building a Chrome app. The app is written with TypeScript (Angular2).

I would like to push notifications. Here's the code :

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    constructor() {
        if(Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
            Notification.requestPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

When gulp build the app, it says :

```
src/scripts/stream/notification.service.ts(6) Cannot find name 'Notification'.
```

I tried to wrap my class inside :

```
/* tslint:disable */
... the code
/* tslint:enable */
```

But it does not change anything.

Is there a way with tslint.json file to tell Typescript that this is a global variable ?

With jshint it would be something like that :

```
"globals": {
   "Notification": false
}
```

Comment: that looks like you are missing type definitions. do you have the chrome.d.ts included in your project?

Comment: I'm new to typescript and tslint. I have no idea what chrome.d.ts is !

Comment: I found the file here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chrome/chrome.d.ts What should I do with it ?

Comment: I'll make an answer. :)

Comment: Sure :)  Thank you !

Comment: Yep, this is actually the TypeScript compiler, not TSLint, warning you about a variable that it thinks doesn't exist. To fix it, you'll want to add a .d.ts file for the Notifications API / Chrome

Comment: I just downloaded this file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chrome/chrome.d.ts to the root of my project, do I have to do anything else ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of options here:

1. Add the following line to the top of your file.

   declare var Notification: any;

   This will make the transpiler pass but won't give you the much of TypeScript's features.
2. Download the definition type (chrome.d.ts).

   [TSD](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) seems to be the most popular definition manager.
   [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) is another promising alternative.

Answer (score 4):

A generic typing file is available via this [GitHub TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3111);

Create a new typing definition file called notification.d.ts and add the following code.

```
type NotificationPermission = "default" | "denied" | "granted";

type NotificationDirection = "auto" | "ltr" | "rtl";

interface NotificationPermissionCallback {
    (permission: NotificationPermission): void;
}

interface NotificationOptions {
    dir?: NotificationDirection;
    lang?: string;
    body?: string;
    tag?: string;
    image?: string;
    icon?: string;
    badge?: string;
    sound?: string;
    vibrate?: number | number[],
    timestamp?: number,
    renotify?: boolean;
    silent?: boolean;
    requireInteraction?: boolean;
    data?: any;
    actions?: NotificationAction[]
}

interface NotificationAction {
    action: string;
    title: string;
    icon?: string;
}

declare class Notification extends EventTarget {
    constructor(title: string, options?: NotificationOptions);

    static readonly permission: NotificationPermission;
    static requestPermission(): Promise<NotificationPermission>;
    static requestPermission(deprecatedCallback: (permission: NotificationPermission) => void): void;

    static readonly maxActions: number;

    onclick: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject;
    onerror: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject;

    close(): void;

    readonly title: string;
    readonly dir: NotificationDirection;
    readonly lang: string;
    readonly body: string;
    readonly tag: string;
    readonly image: string;
    readonly icon: string;
    readonly badge: string;
    readonly sound: string;
    readonly vibrate: number[];
    readonly timestamp: number;
    readonly renotify: boolean;
    readonly silent: boolean;
    readonly requireInteraction: boolean;
    readonly data: any;
    readonly actions: NotificationAction[]
}
```

Making sure the typings file is included in your project (tsconfig.json);

```
    "typeRoots": [
        "typings/notification.d.ts"
    ]
```

You should now be able to access Notification.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing the typing definitions for Chrome.

You can install them using the **tsd** tool.

First you need to install **tsd**.

```
$ npm install tsd -g
```

Then you can use it to install the type definitions for Chrome in your project.

```
$ tsd install chrome
```

You can find more info on tsd [here](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).

Note: make sure you have only 1 tsd file defined for a library.

Comment: I see, thanks ! Just one more thing : Should i exclude typings folder from git or not ?

Comment: you should have a tsd.json file in your project root with all the dependencies so I would say it's fine to exclude it.

Comment: https://github.com/maxime1992/real-debrid-stream you can have a look to the project and the file I have. It does not work. I just ran the 2 commands, I'm missing something here I guess.

Comment: I hadn't seen your tsd link. I'm gonna check to understand better !

Comment: I've copied your repository and I'll try to reproduce the issue :)

Comment: I just pushed where I currently am ! It's in chrome-notif branch, commit "tmp" :)

Comment: one thing, you shouldn't have the chrome.d.ts file in the root only in the typings. :)

Comment: Ok ! I haven't read dts tutorial yet but I'll soon ! Is it working for you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99844/discussion-between-toskv-and-maxime).

Comment: I fixed it, but you have more than one problem in your project. This was just the first :D

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found the d.ts files for the Notifications API, but i have found a little trick.

```
if("Notification" in window){
   let _Notification = window["Notification"];
}
```

_Notification will have the same properties as Notification, and can be used the same. This will get around any errors in TypeScript.