# Typescript error - Property 'permission' not exists on type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this javascript code that shows the current status of notification permission:

main.js

```
var $status = document.getElementById('status');

if ('Notification' in window) {
    $status.innerText = Notification.permission;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Current permission status is
        <b id="status">unavailable</b>
    </p>
    <script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I write the same code in a typescript file I am getting this error:

main.ts

```
var $status = document.getElementById('status');

if ('Notification' in window) {
    $status.innerText = Notification.permission;
}

ERROR - Notification.permission

MESSAGE - Property 'permission' not exists on type
          'new(title: string, options?: NotificationOptions): Notification;
          prototype: Notification;
          requestPermission(callback?: NotificationPermissionCallback): 
          Promise<string>;'
```

How to ignore this error?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620787/2091230).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try casting `Notification` to the `any` type to avoid transpiler errors.

```
if ('Notification' in window) {
    $status.innerText = (Notification as any).permission;
}
```

The other option is to include the `Notification` type's definition.

Comment: It works by casting `Notification` to `any`. How can I include `Notification` type's definition?

Comment: Which library does `Notification` belong to? Typically (with the latest versions of Typescript - 2.0+), you would do:
`npm install @types/{library name}`.

Comment: Notification is part of the browser api no library.